# R convert hexbin object to spatial polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, polygons

I am trying to do some spatial analyses, and wish to allocate my map references to hexagonal areas. I can do this via the hexbin package or ggplot's stat_hexbin.

I wish to access the information within the hexbin/stat_binhex object which defines each hexagon (eg coordinates of each corner and hexagon code). From this I can then create spatial polygons for

1. use in the analyses
2. merging with my map (in order that any plots would be delimited by the country border rather than hexagon borders).

I have been unable to find the where the hexbin object stores the data defining the hexagons (I presume the coordinates of the corners, a hexagon code and references to the map references assigned to each hexagon are tucked away in there somewhere) and would appreciate any help and suggestions.

An attempt to visually show what I am trying to do can be found [here](http://b144-mcv1-mlt.bio.warwick.ac.uk/~ron/so-q1-3.pdf)

Comment: It is not clear with do you want to do. No all people here are familiar with spatial polygons jargon.  Maybe You should add some data to your question and explain better the expected output/transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I mocked up some images to show what I wish to do, but don't have enough reputation points to post them. I will try to think of a better non-visual explanation. I think really my issue is how to access the information (a) defining hexagons on a graph and (b) relating hexagons to data points from a hexbin (package hexbin) or stat_binhex (package ggplot2) object

Comment: you can put the images in anywhere and add a link to them in your questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I need at least 10 reputation points to post images, even if I host them myself, and I'm a newbie around here.

Comment: I know. That why I said put your images in a dropobox for example and and add theirs links(url paths) to the question.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. I read your previous comment as meaning host the images myself (ie still with image-type links), rather than just with http links. Good suggestion and I've put my images into one file and linked them. Cheers.